# Porting to Python3: Function is slow to exit to command prompt

Tags: python-2.7, command-prompt, porting, timing, python-3.4

#### Problem:

I have been porting a function from p2 to p3 (nothing changed except print statements) and according to timing (see below in the sample code), the function runs just as fast as before, but it takes nearly *three seconds* until the prompt shows up again.

To be precise: The output of print is shown immediately, but the prompt stays inactive for another three(?) seconds.

This was never an issue with p2.

Any ideas on what the cause could be or how to fix it?

Edit: With prompt I meant the input prompt of the shell I was using (bash, GNOME Terminal, Fedora20).

#### Sample code:

```
def doStuff():
    startTime = time.time()

    # do some funny stuff here ...

    print(str((time.time() - startTime)/1000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    doStuff()
```

Comment: Which prompt are you talking about?

Comment: Updated post to answer Burhans question about the prompt.

Comment: This could have something to do with the terminal encoding but I'm not sure what it could be.